# error using nodemailer in express js, how to fix that?

Tags: express, nodemailer

errors i got using nodemailer in express js, how to fix that?

app.post('/feedback', function(req, res){
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'kdsingh834@gmail.com',
                pass: ''
            }
        });

```
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'kd <kdsingh834@gmail.com>'
        to:  'kdsinghjob@gmail.com',
        subject: 'feedback submission',
        text: 'your submission with details..Name: '+req.body.name+'Email:'+req.body.email+ 'Message: '+req.body.message,
        html: '<p>your submission with details..</p><ul><li>Name: '+req.body.name+'</li><li>Email: '+req.body.email+'</li><li>Message: '+req.body.message+'</li></ul>'

    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent: '+info.response);
            res.redirect('/');
        }

    });
});
```

[error in nodemailer using express js, how to fix that error!! error occuring when starting the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSnSG.png)

Comment: You need one comma after `from: 'kd <kdsingh834@gmail.com>'`

Comment: Thanks Younel, now its working...